# mapply to run function with various input parameters

Tags: r, simulation, mapply

I want to carry a simulation study where I vary my input parameters. 
Here are the inputs to my function:

```
my.function<-function(rho, psi, beta0 = c(50,50), beta1 = c(1,1), sigma=c(1,1)) {
c(rho,psi,beta0,beta1,sigma)
}
```

I try using expand.grid and mapply to carry the simulation for various input values

```
rho= c(0,.5,.99)
psi=c(0,.5,.99)
beta1.1=c(0,.5,1)
beta1.2=c(0,.5,1)
sigma.1= c(0,1)
sigma.2=c(0,1)

my.grid<- expand.grid(rho,psi,beta1.1,beta1.2,sigma.1,sigma.2)
```

Then I try using mapply:

```
mapply(my.function, x = my.grid[,1], y=my.grid[,2], 
           beta1=c(my.grid[,3],my.grid[,4]), sigma= c(my.grid[,5], my.grid[,6]))
```

The Problem here is with the beta1 term and the sigma term. Instead of treating

```
beta1=c(my.grid[,3],my.grid[,4]) 
sigma= c(my.grid[,5], my.grid[,6]))
```

as a pair, when I use mapply, the function is running over all values within my.grid[,3] and my.grid[,4]

Comment: Use `list` instead of `c` maybe.

Comment: The arguments x and y in your `mapply` are floating there without any function expecting them.